# Position elements in Chrome vs IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some elements that I am trying to position in two rows mathematically.

I have a thumb_container that is a div and is positioned absolutely. Then inside of that using jquery I am loading and appending image thumbnails with this for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    $(img).addClass("thumb");
    $(img).offset({ top:Math.floor(i / 5) * 95, left: (i % 5) * 55 })
    img.src = "images/girl_thumb_" + i + ".jpg";
}
```

Here is the relevant css

```
img, div {
    position:absolute;
}
#thumb_container {
    left:15px;
    top:370px;
}
```

This works in Chrome just fine. I get two rows and five columns all aligned jsut fine, here is a screenshot.

[image: chrome]

But in IE the rows just cascade downward to the right.

[image: ie]

Comment: why not just float with padding?

Comment: Or have a table instead?

Comment: @mplungjan - sounds kinky !

Answer (score 6):

This issue is called the IE "stepdown" bug.

This is supposedly caused because older versions of IE add a hidden `<br>` element.

According to CSS Tricks, you can fix this with the following CSS rule applied to your floated elements:

```
ul#menu li {
    display: inline; /* Prevents "stepdown" */
}
```

See http://css-tricks.com/prevent-menu-stepdown/ for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that sometime too!

Comment: I think `overflow: hidden` might help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by using css() in jquery instead of offset()